# Python: handle sys.exit in unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a management command that can do stuff, or can return a `sys.exit()`.

I'm trying to handle the second case as follows in my unit tests:

```
    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
        call_command('geocode_practices', *args, **opts)
    self.assertEqual(cm.exception, 1)
```

But this gives me:

```
AssertionError: None != 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, what's the best way to handle the different scenarios? At the moment my test will fail if the script does not exit.

Comment: Is this test expected to hit the "do stuff" case, or the `sys.exit()` case? And should this command be calling `sys.exit()` at all?

Comment: Management command should be callable from other code, so raising a `SystemExit` is really a bad idea.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks, how then should I handle an exit from a management command? (I want to fail gracefully in a case where there's no network connection.)

Comment: @Richard https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/#command-exceptions

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the code inside your `with` block doesn't raise an exception. Note that `sys.exit()` just raises a `SystemExit` exception.

And even if it did, the exception will not compare equal to 1. If not `None`, the `cm.exception` attribute contains the exception instance, not a number.

Comment: The odd thing is that if `SystemExit` isn't raised, the test should never even reach the call to `assertEqual`.